# How to use Navigation in JetPack in Anko?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

[image]

I do not know how to declare navHostFragment in anko. It is not a view. More importantly, how to declare the last two attrs   app:xxx?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to create `<fragment>` tags directly from anko.
You should create the NavHostFragment and add it manualy:

```
val finalHost = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.example_graph)

linearLayout {
    id = 1
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(1, finalHost)
        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost) // this is the equivalent to app:defaultNavHost="true"
        .commit()
}
```